# WPF Checkbox change

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am using WPF with MVVM and here is a scenarion.

In xaml file:

```
<CheckBox Content="Show Transactions" Command="{Binding Path=ShowTxnCommand}"
          CommandParameter="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

and "ShowTxnCommand" is properly defined in viewmodel and whenever I check or uncheck the checkbox, the underlying "ShowTxnCommand" executes perfectly.

**Q. I want to track whether the checkbox is checked or unchecked under ShowTxnCommand?**

Comment: Please also share your code of the "ShowTxnCommand" method from the viewmodel. Unsually, you would check this with the command parameter

Comment: public void ExecuteTxnShow(object dataSource, int pageSize, int)
{
 // my code
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the `IsChecked` property to a `bool` source property of the view model to keep track of whether the `CheckBox` is checked or unchecked.

You can then execute the command, or call a method directly, from the setter of the source property:

```
private bool _isChecked;
public bool IsChecked
{
    get { return _isChecked; }
    set
    {
        _isChecked = value;
        //call the method...
        ExecuteTxnShow(...);
        //or execute the command here...
        ShowTxnCommand.Execute(null);
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<CheckBox Content="Show Transactions" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
```